# button in jquery tabs visible in all tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a button in jquery tabs that is visible in all tabs, I changed the css of the jquery tabs to make the border closed to the tabs, the border near the button is missing.

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button style="margin: 1em 1.4em">Button</button>
    <div id="tab-1">Hello World 1</div>
    <div id="tab-2">Hello World 2</div>
    <div id="tab-3">Hello World 3</div>
    <div id="tab-4">Hello World 4</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

CSS

```
#tabs {
    padding: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-width: 0px;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    padding-left: 0px;
    background: transparent;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
}

.ui-tabs-selected {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvtugp6m/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to wrap your button in a div with its own border.
Your problem is that the button is pushing down your tab content containers.

[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nvtugp6m/1/)

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
      <li> <a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="button-wrapper">
    <button style="margin: 1em 1.4em">Button</button>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-1">Hello World 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2">Hello World 2</div>
  <div id="tab-3">Hello World 3</div>
  <div id="tab-4">Hello World 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
$('#tabs').tabs();
```

```css
#tabs {
  padding: 0px;
  background: none;
  border-width: 0px;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  padding-left: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
}
#tabs .btn-wrapper {
  border: 0 solid #aaaaaa;
  border-width: 0px 1px;
}
.ui-tabs-selected {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button style="margin: 1em 1.4em">Button</button>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-1">Hello World 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2">Hello World 2</div>
  <div id="tab-3">Hello World 3</div>
  <div id="tab-4">Hello World 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean `#btn-wrapper` instead of `#tabs .btn-wrapper`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your button in a div and give it border from left and right as :

```
<div class="btn-wrapper">
     <button style="margin: 1em 1.4em">Button</button>
</div>

.btn-wrapper{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```